# Integrating a interactive linux terminal using node.js into a webpage

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need to develop an application using node js which will run an interactive shell script ( which gets some input from the user )and the execution logs must be displayed in the same web page.

Can anyone please let me know how to integrate a interactive/responsive linux terminal into a web page using node.js.

Thanks,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to integrate terminal like feature into your webpage you can try xtrem.js.

link: https://xtermjs.org/

It easy to use and well documented.